# Question about Volume of a cube

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $K_1,K_2,..... $ be cubes in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} v(K_n) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

My teacher said that for each $n$, we can choose a rectangle $Q_n$ such that

$$ K_n \subset Int Q_n $$

and

$$ v(Q_n) \leq 2 v(K_n) $$

I really cannot understand why we can choose such $Q_n$. I really need some help. Thanks.

Comment: If you multiply each side length from $K_n$ by a factor $\sqrt[n]{2} = 2^{1/n}$, then you get a bigger cube $Q_n$ that contains $K_n$ in its interior, and its $n$-volume is the double of the original volume. Note that the factor chosen depends on $n$. ***Edit:*** You used $n$ in two senses, which is kind of bad. I was talking about the dimensional $n$ from your $\mathbb{R}^n$, not the $n$ that enumerated each instance of a cube.

Comment: If $K_n$ has side length $\ell_n$, you could choose $Q_n$ to be a cube of side length $(\sqrt[2n]{2})\ell_n$ with the same center point as $K_n$.  Since $\sqrt[2n]{2}> 1$ (for $n$ finite), then $K_n \subset \text{interior}(Q_n)$ is clear, and $v(Q_n) = \sqrt{2} v(K_n) < 2v(K_n)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $K$ is the cube $[x_1,x_1 + \delta] \times \cdots \times [x_n,x_n + \delta]$. The volume of $K$ is $\delta^n$. Define
$$ Q = [x_1 - \epsilon, x_1 + \delta + \epsilon] \times \cdots \times [x_n - \epsilon,x_n + \delta + \epsilon].$$
You should be able to verify that $K \subset \mathrm{int}\, Q$. Observe the volume of $Q$ is $(\delta + 2\epsilon)^n$, so that $v(Q) < 2 v(K)$ if $\epsilon$ is small enough. Precisely, if $$ 0 < \epsilon < \frac{(2^{1/n} - 1)\delta}{2}.$$

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have one question: Are we allow to choose $\epsilon > 0$ in such a way? This always confuses me. Why can we choose such an $\epsilon $ less than such expression?

Comment: Look at it this way: the $\epsilon$ measures how much the cube is being stretched. If you stretch it a little bit its volume will increase a little, if you stretch it a lot its volume will increase by a lot. The particular upper bound of $\epsilon$ guarantees that the volume at most doubles. So any smaller $\epsilon$ will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm going to use $d$ to denote the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ in what follows, not $n$ as this will be an index.)

Just consider any cube $K$ of legth $\ell$ so that $|K|=\ell^{d}$.  If we increase the length by some $\delta>0$, we get another cube (rectangle) $Q$ such that $Q$ has length $\ell+\delta$ and $|Q|=(\ell+\delta)^{d}$.  The cube $K$ clearly fits inside of $Q$, and indeed it is clear that $K\subset Q^{\circ}$ since $\delta>0$.

A common technique is to apply the $\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n}}$ trick.  You fatten the collection of cubes $\{K_{n}\}_{n}$ by a positive length (it doesn't matter by what length exactly) such that the resulting fattened cubes $\{Q_{n}\}_{n}$ satisfy $|Q_{n}|=|K_{n}|+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}.$  Then by our assumption, $$\sum|Q_{n}|=\sum|K_{n}|+\epsilon\sum 2^{-(n+1)}=\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.$$

Note in the present situation, by fattening the cubes $K_{n}$ to get cubes $Q_{n}$, we get an open cover and compactness arguments can be used, i.e. a finite number of the $Q_{n}^{\circ}$ cover all of the $K_{n}.$